# Inserting tuples inside an inner bag using Pig Latin - Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, apache-pig-grunt

I am trying to create the following format of relation using Pig Latin:

userid, day, {(pid,fulldate, x,y),(pid,fulldate, x,y), ...}

Relation description: Each user (userid) in each day (day) has purchased multiple products (pid)

I am Loading the data into:

```
A= LOAD '**from a HDFS URL**' AS (pid: chararray,userid: 
chararray,day:int,fulldate: chararray,x: chararray,y:chararray);
B= GROUP A BY (userid, day);
Describe B;
```

B: {group: (userid: chararray,day: int),A: {(pid: chararray,day: int,fulldate: chararray,x: chararray,userid: chararray,y: chararray)}}

```
C= FOREACH B FLATTEN(B) AS (userid,day), $1.pid, $1.fulldate,$1.x,$1.y;
Describe C;
```

C: {userid: chararray,day: int,{(pid: chararray)}},{(fulldate: chararray)},{(x: chararray)},{(y: chararray)}}

The result of Describe C does not give the format I want ! What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The `DESCRIBE B` output above would be impossible. I think you have `B` where it should read `A`, like: `B: {group: (userid: chararray,day: int),A: {(pid: chararray,day: int,fulldate: chararray,x: chararray,userid: chararray,y: chararray)}}` My answer assumes the bag is named `A` instead.

Comment: You are right, just edited the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct till the `GROUP BY` part. After that however you are trying to do something messy. I'm actually not sure what is happening for your alias `C`. To arrive at the format you are looking for, you will need a nested foreach.

```
C = FOREACH B {
         data = A.pid, A.fulldate, A.x, A.y;
         GENERATE FLATTEN(group), data;
    }
```

This allows C to have one record for each `(userid, day)` and all the corresponding `(pid,fulldate, x, y)` tuples in a bag.
You can read more about nested foreach here: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-pig/9781449317881/ch06.html (Search for nested foreach in that link).

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that `B` is almost what you're looking for, except you would like the tuple containing `userid` and `day` to be flattened, and you would like only `pid`, `fulldate`, `x`, and `y` to appear in the bag.

First, you want to flatten the tuple `group` which has fields `userid` and `day`, not the bag `A` which contains multiple tuples. Flattening `group` unnests the tuple, which only has 1 set of unique values for each row, whereas flattening the bag `A` would effectively ungroup your previous `GROUP BY` statement since the values in the bag `A` are not unique. So the first part should read `C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS (userid, day);`

Next, you want to keep `pid`, `fulldate`, `x`, and `y` in separate tuples for each record, but the way you've selected them essentially makes a bag of all the `pid` values, a bag of all the `fulldate` values, etc. Instead, try selecting these fields in a way that keeps the tuples nested in the bag:

```
C = FOREACH B GENERATE 
    FLATTEN(group) AS (userid, day), 
    A.(pid, fulldate, x, y) AS A;
```